# Swift: Table view superclass error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, superclass

I have created a slide out menu using Swift. I have done this many times before, but when I created it today, I get this error (see screenshot). It could just be a simple mistake I have made.

Here is the code, that I think is causing the problem:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil{
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell!.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.darkTextColor()

        let selectedView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell!.frame.size.width, height: cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)

        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
    }

    cell!.textLabel!.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

UPDATE: I have tried removing `override`

[image]

Hope someone can help!

Comment: @RDC Thanks for the suggestion, but did not work. See update

Comment: Did you actually **implement the protocols** needed for the `UITableView` delegates? `class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { /* ... */ }`

Comment: I might be wrong, but just for the sake of completeness... are you subclassing `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`? If the second one, is it configured with static cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method does not override any method of the superclass because the signature is wrong.

The correct signature is

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

All parameters are non-optional types.

And use also the recommended method

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier,
                                           forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

which also returns always a non-optional type

Comment: Thanks for your help! The first part of answer has solved the problem (the signature part) but the let cell, I get "unresolved identifier 'cell Identifier'" Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `cellIdentifier` use your literal `"Cell"` and remove the `nil` check and all unnecessary exclamation marks.

Comment: Thank you ever so much! You answer has solved my problem! Thanks for your help! 

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your class implements `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // All your methods here
}
```

You won't need `override` keyword unless any other superclass already implements those methods.

Comment: Thanks ever so much! Part of your answer has solved my problem, but when I remove `override` I get, use of unresolved identifier 'cell Identifier'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See this works for me

- Just confirm `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`
- Implement required methods

---

```
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    let containArray = ["One","two","three","four","five"]


    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: Table view data source and delegate methods

    //Number of rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return containArray.count
    }

    //Prepare Custom Cell
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let identifier = "simpleTextCell"
        var cell: SimpleTextCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? SimpleTextCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SimpleTextCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? SimpleTextCell
        }

        let dayName = containArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblProductName.text = dayName


        return cell
    }

    //Handle click
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("productListSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to removing "!", declaration for this function is:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

and make sure you have set delegate and datasource of tableview to "self"

Comment: Thank you. Sadly your answer did not solve my problem